# python 3.11.3 compiled version is slower than the interpreted version

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

in python 3.11.3 the compiled version is slower than the interpreted version, I did the tests compiling with both pyinstaller 5.11.0 and cx_freeze, which brought the performance equal to the compiled version of python 3.9.

Compiled 3.9 and 3.11.3
test fib: 452.0 ms
test geometry: 1026.0 ms
test data: 54.0 ms

Without compiling
test fib: 283.0 ms
test geometry: 437.0 ms
test data: 30.0 ms

test code:

```
import time
import math
import random
import hashlib
import os
import sys

def fib(n):
    if(n == 0 or n == 1):
        return n 
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)      

def test_geometry(vector3_1, vector3_2, radius1, radius2, radius3):
    distance = math.sqrt((vector3_2[0] - vector3_1[0])**2 + (vector3_2[1] - vector3_1[1])**2 + (vector3_2[2] - vector3_1[2])**2)
    distance_between_centers = math.sqrt((vector3_2[0] - vector3_1[0])**2 + (vector3_2[1] - vector3_1[1])**2 + (vector3_2[2] - vector3_1[2])**2)
    sphere_volume = (4/3) * math.pi * (radius3**3)

def load_data():
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
    data_file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, 'data.txt')
    try:
        with open(data_file_path, "r") as f:
            data = f.read()
            return data
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Arquivo 'data.txt' não encontrado.")


start_fib = time.time()
result_fib = fib(32)
finish_fib = time.time()

vector3_1 = (random.uniform(1, 10), random.uniform(1, 10), random.uniform(1, 10))
vector3_2 = (random.uniform(1, 10), random.uniform(1, 10), random.uniform(1, 10))
radius1 = random.uniform(1, 10)
radius2 = random.uniform(1, 10)
radius3 = random.uniform(1, 10)
start_geometry = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    result_geometry = test_geometry(vector3_1, vector3_2, radius1, radius2, radius3)
finish_geometry = time.time()

start_data = time.time()
load_data()
finish_data = time.time()

print("python:")
print(f"teste fib: {round((finish_fib-start_fib)*1000, 0)} ms")
print(f"teste geometry: {round((finish_geometry-start_geometry)*1000, 0)} ms")
print(f"teste data: {round((finish_data-start_data)*1000, 0)} ms\n")
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I am curious

I was expecting that compiled version runs faster

Comment: cx_freeze isn't a "compiler" at all, and nothing ever claimed it was. It's just a packager, packaging your interpreter and files for it to run into an executable; it then has to unpack the interpreter and its dependencies _in addition to_ all the normal runtime work, so _of course_ it's slower.

Comment: The same thing is true for pyinstaller and every other similar tool. None of them are compilers, all of them are still interpreting your code (or at least interpreting Python bytecode, same as would be if you had a directory of `.pyc` files)

Comment: BTW, if you're looking for a language that _does_ genuinely compile, see [Julia](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/). Granted, it usually compiles just-ahead-of-time to result in a user experience very much like that of an interpreted language, but [that isn't the only option](https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/).